# What is the passive noun form of "user"?

Tags: nouns, passive-voice

I was reading [Richard Stallman's page on why you should not use Facebook](https://stallman.org/facebook.html) and he refers to Facebook users as "useds" with this explanation:

> We call them 'useds' rather than 'users' because Facebook is using them, not vice versa.

"Useds" sounds awkward to my ear. Is this grammatically correct, or would be more correct to say "usees"?

Comment: Stallman was making up the word, and the fact that it still sounds strange shows that it didn't catch on. This has happened to Stallman before, but he's also had some successes, so he keeps trying.

Comment: @JohnLawler I guess my question is: did he make it up correctly?

Comment: Who's to say whether it's "correct"? There's no real [Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) that makes such decisions, you know; it's everybody for themselves in language. If anybody wants to use the word that way, they can see whether it works for them. History will decide in the long run.

Comment: I suspect "pawn" would be the closest "real" word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a made up word.

As a made up word, it's not one that I think would even theoretically make its way into our language. The problem with it isn't necessarily its construction, but how difficult it is to pronounce. Given how awkward it is to say, I think very few people would pick it up as something they'd want to say or otherwise use.

(As opposed to the recent **levidrome**, which is easy to pronounce, clever, and has a certain sentimentality because of its young inventor Levi.)

Rather than saying **useds**, I think most people would choose to say **the used** instead. In no way does it make sense to me that he would need to make up a word, and one that's difficult to say, rather than adopt an already existing construction that makes the same point. Perhaps he wanted a single word.

But the word **usees** actually *does* exist. However, I suspect that Stallman was looking for something that implied a past tense. Otherwise, why would he not have used the real **usees**? Or maybe he was just trying to make some kind of point.

It's not so much because it's fictional that I would argue **useds** is ungrammatical, but because I can't think of any parallel constructions where something similar does make sense.

I would argue that **levidrome** is grammatically correct (despite not being in the dictionary) but **useds** is not. (Insofar as you can claim that either is grammatically correct or not.)

Comment: I think I prefer "usee" because it allows other constructions like "useebase", "usee interface", "usee data" etc that don't really work for "used". The point you make about the lack of parallel constructions being why it feels incorrect (despite being "made up") is something I was trying to put my finger on, thanks.